Issue finding #import <FxPlug/FxPlugSDK.h> in Xcode following Apple tutorial
I'm following Apple's tutorial to build an FXPlug plugin manually: Building an FXPlug Plug-In Manually. I've followed every step detailed in the tutorial, but I'm having trouble finding the #import <FxPlug/FxPlugSDK.h> header in Xcode.
I've double-checked that I've followed all instructions correctly, including installing the necessary SDK files, but Xcode still can't find this header. I've reviewed my header search paths and inclusion paths configuration, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.
Has anyone had a similar experience or have any idea why Xcode can't find this header even after following the tutorial step-by-step?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
